# Trying to stream files from an FTP

Tags: ruby, ftp

I am trying to access an FTP (NCBI genomes bank) and loop through the files and read them.

I got the part where I can read a local file and I can connect to a FTP but I can't find what I should do to read files directly from the FTP (if possible without having to download it).

```
    ftp         = Net::FTP.new("ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov")
    ftp.passive = true
    ftp.login
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18772703/read-a-file-in-buffer-from-ftp-python) but it's in Python and I am having trouble finding equivalent methods and libraries.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What your looking for is [Net::FTP](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/ftp/rdoc/Net/FTP.html#method-i-gettextfile)

```
ftp = Net::FTP.new("ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov")
ftp.passive = true
ftp.login
files = ftp.chdir('/foo')
ftp.gettextfile('test.txt') do |txt|

  # do something with text
end
ftp.close
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help ! It works exactly the way I want ! In case someone with the same problem is wondering gettextfile return each line of the document as txt (in that case)