# How to read the header of WAV file from FTP directly without downloading whole file in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ftp, wav, ftplib

I want to read the WAV file (which is in my FTP server) directly from FTP server without downloading it into my PC in Python. Is it possible and if yes the how?

I tried this solution [Read a file in buffer from ftp python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18772703/read-a-file-in-buffer-from-ftp-python) but it didn't work. I have .wav audio file. I want to read the file and get details from that .wav file like file size, byte rate, etc.

My code which in which I was able to read the WAV files locally:

```
import struct

from ftplib import FTP

global ftp
ftp = FTP('****', user='user-****', passwd='********')

fin = open("C3.WAV", "rb") 
chunkID = fin.read(4) 
print("ChunkID=", chunkID)

chunkSizeString = fin.read(4) # Total Size of File in Bytes - 8 Bytes
chunkSize = struct.unpack('I', chunkSizeString) # 'I' Format is to to treat the 4 bytes as unsigned 32-bit inter
totalSize = chunkSize[0]+8 # The subscript is used because struct unpack returns everything as tuple
print("TotalSize=", totalSize)
```

Comment: So you *only* have an FTP server, not HTTP for example?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I was able to get the details locally but when I tried using the  previous solution above I was not able to read the wav file only . If i somehow manage to read the WAV file  from  FTP then I now how to get the details of WAV files

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I have done the edit . You can see it now

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Yes

Comment: @MartinPrikryl okay sorry for that . Can you help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a quick implementation, you can make use of my `FtpFile` class from:
[Get files names inside a zip file on FTP server without downloading whole archive](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53143518/850848#53144697)

```
ftp = FTP(...)
fin = FtpFile(ftp, "C3.WAV")
# The rest of the code is the same
```

The code is bit inefficient though, as each `fin.read` will open a new download data connection.

---

For a more efficient implementation, just download whole header at once (I do not know WAV header structure, I'm downloading 10 KB here as an example):

```
from io import BytesIO

ftp = FTP(...)
fin = BytesIO(FtpFile(ftp, "C3.WAV").read(10240))
# The rest of the code is the same
```